# sum function not showing any value php and postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Trying to get a sum of a row "sub_total" on my table name "tree_solds" but my code does not show anything.

```
$tval = "SELECT SUM(sub_total) AS rtotal FROM tree_solds";
$tvalue = pg_query($tval);
$trev = pg_fetch_assoc($tvalue);
echo $trev['rtotal'];
```

When it's runs, it just an empty line. any suggestions?

[image: db]

Comment: From the Postgres manual: It should be noted that except for count, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected. In particular, sum of no rows returns null, not zero as one might expect, and array_agg returns null rather than an empty array when there are no input rows. The coalesce function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for null when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

avoid null values by IsNull(sub_total, 0) or COALESCE(sub_total,0) to ensure it is always 0 at minimum.

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(sub_total,0)) AS rtotal FROM tree_solds
```

Comment: thanks for you help but after changing it I still get an empty result.